# mailto: link is not working in mail() function while sending email in php

Tags: php, email, sendmail, mailto

I am sending email using mail() function in PHP.
I am using following code

`<a href="mailto:info@vivahsuchak.com">send email</a>`

code to link email.

Aafter sending email using PHP , I have checked in mail and when I click on "send email" link it showing me following message 
"Sorry, the page you requested was not found."

how can i use "mailto:" link in mail() function.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question `how can i use "mailto:" link in mail() function.` doesn't make any sense. What ***exactly*** are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to use email link in mail while sending email using PHP.

Comment: It doesn't work like that. "mailto:" pops up the clients default mail composer. The mail() function dispatches an email to the smtp configured in php.ini - They are not connected.

Comment: @suhaspandit: http://php.net/mail and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto -- read both the links first.

Comment: `mailto:` and PHP's `mail()` are night and day different.

Answer (score 0):

mailto:example@example.com and the php mail() function are to entirely different things, they are not even the same language, mailto is HTML and mail() is php. If you want to **send** an email to someone from your site you need:

1. The mail module installed on your server - get intouch with your hosting provider and ask.
2. The correct script to send the mail - for a simple email check w3schools? http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp

If you want to open your clients email program use mailto as you have above.

Answer (score 0):

`mailto:` links are handled by receiver's email client. If they are not working properly then it's on the 3 reasons:

1) Email client doesn't have that functionality or it's turned off.

2) Syntax errors in the HTML you send. This may be due to incorrect encoding or typo's in your server-side code when generating it (for ex. unclosed HTML tags or missing chars). Also check how your quote chars are encoded in `href=""`.

3) Default email application is not set in your OS configuration. Usually this is set automatically when you install email client. On windows it's in `Control Panel > Default Programs > Set program access and computer defaults`. If there is no email client installed and you're viewing email from within your browser. Then check your browser settings. For ex. [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-program-used-open-email-links). (IE uses OS settings somewhere since version 9 or 10)